# Implement Elasticsearch Multi-tenancy using an Index per tenant or 10 index per tenant which is better approach

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, multi-tenant, sharding, opensearch

Implement Elasticsearch Multi-tenancy using an **Index per tenant** or **10 index per tenant** which is a better approach, by considering Security, Scalability, Cost-effectiveness, Complexity

E.g.

Approach 1: 4TB of data with 1000 tenants implemented using **Index per tenant** or **10 index per tenant**

Approach 2: 4TB of data with 1000 tenants implemented using **10 index per tenant**

which approach is better, by considering Security, Scalability, Cost-effectiveness, Complexity

Best practices for Elasticsearch